# share action provider is not working

Tags: android-intent

i want to share a layout as an image. code listed below is working fine for the save action button but not for share action button. share action button remains unresponsive. i am unable to figure it out what is wrong.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.eid_card_final, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    myshare = (ShareActionProvider)item.getActionProvider();
    String sharestate = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    RelativeLayout rlShareLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    Bitmap sharebitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rlShareLayout.getWidth(), rlShareLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas sharecanvas = new Canvas(sharebitmap);
    rlShareLayout.draw(sharecanvas);
    try{
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(sharestate)) {

            Random sharerand = new Random();
            int sharerandnum = sharerand.nextInt(1000);
            String sharefilename = sharerandnum + ".jpeg";

            sharef = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),sharefilename);

            FileOutputStream shareout = new FileOutputStream(sharef);
            boolean success = sharebitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, shareout);

    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent shareintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareintent.setType("image/*");
    Uri shareuri = Uri.fromFile(sharef);
    shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareuri.toString());
    shareintent.setData(shareuri);
    myshare.setShareIntent(shareintent);
    return true;

}
```

i am using same code (except intent part of code) to save file and it is working perfectly fine, what is strange is same code should at least save file automatically upon (if not send using ACTION_SEND) when options menu get created/loaded , but code for saving file is also not working (along with the intent part of code)and the worst part is that there is no error. i am stuck up. please guide what is going wrong